# Django validate property

Tags: python, django, validation

Is there any way to apply a Django validator to a property instead of a field?

I have a field dob and a property age tied to that field. I'll like to guarantee that age cannot be smaller than 18.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Use the validator for a function that will subtract the desired years from the current time.